# MySQL - Update Field to Another Field's Value

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am sturggling to get the following query working:

```
UPDATE user_stock SET user_stock1 = user_stock2 
WHERE user_stock1 = NULL AND user_id = 'mike';
```

The query is accepted with no syntax errors, although it does not set user_stock1 to the value of user_stock2, any ideas?

Comment: Your query seems to be fine. Share some sample data to identify the issues

Comment: A column is never equal to null. You have to change it to *WHERE user_stock1 IS  NULL*

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, a column is never equal to `NULL`. You have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`:

```
UPDATE user_stock SET user_stock1 = user_stock2 
WHERE user_stock1 IS NULL AND user_id = 'mike';
```